# Apply and keyword arguments in lisp

Tags: lisp, keyword, apply

I can use keyword parameters in LISP

```
(member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq)
```

However, when I tried to use apply to invoke member method

```
(apply #'member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq)
```

I have error message as follows:

```
MEMBER: keyword arguments in (:TEST) should occur pairwise
 [Condition of type SYSTEM::SIMPLE-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

The solution was

```
(apply #'member 'a '(a b c) '(:test eq))
```

Whereas without the keyword arguments

```
(apply #'member 'a '((a b c)))
```

What's the logic behind this? Why '(:test #'eq) raises an error?

### ADDED

This is the reason why I asked this question.
I have code from ANSI Common Lispbook page 103.

```
(defun our-adjoin (obj lst &rest args)
       (if (apply #'member obj lst args)
           lst
           (cons obj lst)))
```

When I tried `(our-adjoin 'a '(a b c))` it returns the result `(A B C)`, but the our-adjoin can't be translated as `(apply #'member 'a '(a b c))`, because it will raise an error (as is asked in [Apply and keyword arguments in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269972/apply-and-keyword-arguments-in-lisp)).

What I can think about is that the value from `&rest args` is given to make something like `(apply #member 'a '(a b c) '())` not to raise an error.

Comment: Using `funcall` is probably clearer than contortions with `apply`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`apply` expects its final argument to be a list. That is,

```
(apply #'foo (list 1 2 3)) == (foo 1 2 3)
(apply #'member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq) == ??? ; is an error - #'eq isn't a list
```

I don't know what `apply` is making of `#'eq` (a function) where a list is expected, but that's the problem.

You might be looking for `funcall` instead of `apply`:

```
(funcall #'foo 1 2 3) == (foo 1 2 3)
(funcall #'member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq) == (member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq)
```

### Edit: `(apply #'member 'a '(a b c))`

This is the same as

```
(member 'a 'a 'b 'c)
```

which of course is nonsense. Think of `apply` as "expanding" its last argument.

### Edit 2: The `our-adjoin` code

```
(our-adjoin 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq)
;; is equivalent to
(if (apply #'member 'a '(a b c) (list :test #'eq))
    lst
  (cons obj lst))
;; is equivalent to
(if (member 'a '(a b c) :test #'eq) ...)

(our-adjoin 'a '(a b c))
;; is equivalent to
(if (apply #'member 'a '(a b c) (list)) ...) ; (list) == nil
;; is equivalent to
(if (member 'a '(a b c)) ...)
```

So your hypothesis (that the equivalent was `(apply #'member 'a '(a b c) '())`) is correct. (FYI, there is no difference between `nil`, `'nil`, `()`, `'()`, and `(list)`.)

Answer (score 4):

[APPLY](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_apply.htm) is provided so that we can call functions with a computed argument list.

`APPLY` has the following syntax:

```
apply function &rest args+ => result*
```

- the first parameter is a function
- then several arguments, at least one, where the last argument needs to be a list